# Create a brand new type of searchable tree in JSON for Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, list

I am thinking of a new way to extract data from JSON. The following example is what I want:

- Look for a key and value pair and give me that object.
- Inside that object, give me the value to this key.

I want to get the `power` of `knighthero` in the following JSON, by telling it to find the username `knighthero`. This is really difficult, and I've tried `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`, but can't figure it out. I know the length is 3, but now what?

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "power": 75,
        "registrant": {
            "group": "elf",
            "username": "kevin23"
        }
    },
    {
        "power": 34,
        "registrant": {
            "group": "fairy",
            "username": "msi56"
        }
    },
    {
        "power": 150,
        "registrant": {
            "group": "orc",
            "username": "knighthero"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I have tried `JsonPath` and all I get is `[]` when I print the string. I have tried `JSONArray`, but can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Please show any code and why exactly you failed. JSONArray and JSONObject are one way to do that and it's normally fairly easy to iterate over the objects and look for a specific element - as long as the structure stays the same, which is something only you know.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? If you can load the JSON items as objects then searching them will be easy, and the code should be easier to read than using raw JSON objects

Comment: @Thomas actually the structure per say doesn't change but key : value pairs get added in this JSON. For example If knighthero gets a super power, then superpower : 180 gets added under "registrant" alongside power. So it gets hard to say find me a "registrant" that matches this username that does not have a superpower : xx key / value pair

Comment: What's so hard about that? Iterate over the "registrants" and check for username and superpower not being present.

Answer (score 0):

With org.json librairy and your json described.

```
JSONObject jo0  = new JSONObject("{\"data\": ["
            + "{\"power\": 75,"
            + "\"registrant\": {\"group\": \"elf\",\"username\": \"kevin23\"}},"
            + "{\"power\": 34,"
            + "\"registrant\": {\"group\": \"fairy\",\"username\": \"msi56\"}},"
            + "{\"power\": 150,"
            + "\"registrant\": {\"group\": \"orc\",\"username\": \"knighthero\"}}"
            + "]}");
JSONArray ja = jo0.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
     if(ja.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("registrant").getString("username").equals("knighthero")){
            System.out.println(ja.getJSONObject(i).getInt("power"));
            break;
     }
}
```

EDIT
My bad, I make a mistake, here the good version

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i'm getting an incompatible types error : String cannot be converted to Int. on "registrant" and "power"

Comment: Thank you! It worked for this JSON but how do I iterate when I don't know there are 3?